# Can't use "__has_include" preprocessor in Keil IDE

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, keil

I'm using `Keil` to code for STM32 microcontrollers. In `main.h` file, I use this code:

```
#if defined __has_include //Keil recognizes this preprocessor. If it was unavailable, Keil would have marked it as gray
#if __has_include("Debugg.h")
    #include "Debugg.h"
#endif
#endif
```

This, checks if the `Debugg.h` file exists. Let's imagine I have a `#define` in `Debugg.h` file:

```
#define    DEBUGGING    1
```

Now, I expect that in `main.h`, the `DEBUGGING` is defined. Again `main.h`:

```
#if defined __has_include //Keil recognizes this preprocessor. If it was unavailable, Keil would have marked it as gray
#if __has_include("Debugg.h")
    #include "Debugg.h"
#endif
#endif

#ifdef  DEBUGGING
#define MAIN_DEBUG                  1 //This line runs
#else
#define MAIN_DEBUG                  0 //Keil IDE mark this line as gray, meaning "unavailable code"
#endif
```

But, whenever I try to print `MAIN_DEBUG` or use it, it is `0`!

**NOTE:**
It seems that Keil IDE recognizes the `__has_include` preprocessor, but the compiler DOES NOT; because when I comment out these lines:

```
//#if defined __has_include
#if __has_include("Debugg.h")
    #include "Debugg.h"
#endif
//#endif
```

I get these errors:

```
compiling main.c...
..\Library\main.h(5): error:  #59: function call is not allowed in a constant expression
  #if __has_include("Debugg.h")
..\Library\main.h(5): error:  #31: expression must have integral type
  #if __has_include("Debugg.h")
..\Library\main.c: 0 warnings, 2 errors
```

I also use the `default ARM compiler version 5`. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Suggestions?  Do not rely on this non-standard `__has_include()` macro.  If your compiler does not support it then I don't see any alternative, anyway.  Most of the C-writing world does without such a feature.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But the IDE recognizes that. It uses the same compiler. Is it possible that the IDE recognizes that but the compiler does not??

Comment: @MohammadKholghi You can check that by inserting `#error __has_include is defined` after `#if defined __has_include`

Comment: @MohammadKholghi, the IDE is not necessarily using the compiler to determine whether the macro is known.  It might even be that it doesn't check it at all, maybe on account of the form of its name (the leading double underscore puts this macro's name in a special class of names reserved for the C language implementation).  But even if there were a way to tell the compiler to recognize the macro, my advice would still be to avoid its use.  It is non-standard, and it does not appear to be providing anything that is particularly useful.

Comment: @user3386109 I did this and got the error: 
`#if defined __has_include
        #if __has_include("Debugg.h")
         #include "Debugg.h"
        #endif
#else
        #error __has_include is defined 
#endif`
This means the compiler doesn't understand the `__has_include`. What can I do?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, but I have to use the ARM compiler. It's for STM32 microcontrollers.

Comment: You technically could generate C code for the ARM compiler. And [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) could be used as a cross-compiler for ARM. It is open source, you could compile GCC from its source code

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks a lot. What is the standard way to check if a file is available?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks. I've checked the GCC by STM32CubeIDE, and it's not that professional, plus lots of other problems that I can't remember exactly. I have to use ARM.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi, there is no standard way in C source code to check whether a header is available.  Rather, there are conventional mechanisms based on standard language features for approaching the same problem that you are trying to solve by checking whether a file is available.  For instance, most compilers permit you to specify macro definitions on the command line.

Comment: Or there are systems for build-time customization of your source code, such as the Autotools and CMake.  These particular tools might not be available to you, but for a simple job such as you describe, it would not be too hard to write a little script that serves.  I take this to be the direction that Basile had in mind when he suggested that you write a code generator (which is an altogether different thing from a compiler).

Comment: What is the _real problem_ you like to solve?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you very much, but I've done a lot to use the Keil compiler. The GCC ignores a lot of warnings that Keil's doesn't. I've test both. The Keil is the best for my job...

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have explained it easily, but I have about 50 other files, that must be compiled using the Keil. I was looking if I can add `__has_include` to Keil's comiler.

Comment: @thebusybee I have 4 threads in the microcontroller's code, and let's imagine 40 libraries. Each thread uses 10 of them. I also have a `Debugg.h` file. In this file, I define which threads can be debugged. If a thread's debug is ON, some parts of its libraries are also available for debugging. As they are libraries, I have these files for each library: a `libX.c`, a `libX.h` and `libX_conf.h` file. the checking for `Debugg.h` is in config file. If it was available, it checks for the prints of a specific thread. If not, debugging is deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

Do not use non-portable extensions like `__has_include`. Build systems are used to detect information about environment, like available headers.

For example, CMake build system has [`check_include_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFile.html) that you can check if an include file exists. Then if the include file `Debugg.h` (why upper+lower case mix?) exists, then add a macro `HAS_DEBUGG_H` to compilation and if that macro is defined, then include the header.

> a libX.c, a libX.h and libX_conf.h file. the checking for Debugg.h is in config file. If it was available, it checks for the prints of a specific thread. If not, debugging is deactivated

That should be done with a macro, not with "detecting header file". There should be a macro, called like `LIBX_DEBUG_ENABLE` and if defined, `libX` should output debugging information. I.e. it is a user configuration setting done with a macro, not with deleting a file.